# How serialize inbuilt objects in XML C#?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have complex system of classes referenct each other. I using XML serialize for saving my DataGrids.

Classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class CompJobArray
{
    [XmlElement("Room")]
    public ObservableCollection<Room> RoomList = new ObservableCollection<Room>();
    public CompJobArray() { }
}

public class Room
{
    public string roomName { get; set; }
    public double floorSquare { get; set; }
    public double ceilingSquare { get; set; }
    public double wallsSquare { get; set; }
    public double floorPerimeter { get; set; }
    public double ceilingPerimeter { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CompJob> CompJobsCollection{ get; set; }

    public Room() { }

    public Room(string Name, double fS,double cS,double wS,double fP,double cP)
    {
        roomName = Name;
        floorSquare = fS;
        ceilingSquare = cS;
        wallsSquare = wS;
        floorPerimeter = fP;
        ceilingPerimeter = cP;
        CompJobsCollection = new ObservableCollection<CompJob>();
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class CompJob
{
    public job CompJobjob { get; set; }
    public float Count { get; set; }
    public float TotalPrice { get; set; }

   public CompJob() { }

    public CompJob(job tempJob, float count)
    {
        CompJobjob = tempJob;
        Count = count;
        TotalPrice = tempJob.price*count;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class job
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
    public string measure { get; set; }

    public job() { }

    public job(int t1, string t2, float t3, string t4)
    {
        id = t1;
        name = t2;
        price = t3;
        measure = t4;
    }
}
```

All classes work in chain: CompJobArray->Room->CompJob->Job.

Furhter, XAML and serialize:

```
private void SaveMenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter swr = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath))
        {
            CompJobArray tempJobArray = new CompJobArray();
            tempJobArray.RoomList = RoomList;

            deserializerCJA.Serialize(swr, tempJobArray);
        }
    }

<DataGrid  Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompJobsCollection}"  CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Наименование элемента" Binding="{ Binding Path=CompJobjob.name, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество" Binding="{Binding Path=Count ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сумма" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice,Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

At the end - job is not saved:

```
<CompJobsCollection>
  <CompJob>
    <Count>12</Count>
    <TotalPrice>150</TotalPrice>
  </CompJob>
</CompJobsCollection>
```

Detailed explanation: I deserialize XML with classes Room to ObservableCollection, then i assign Obs. Collection to DataGrid. When i edit datagrid and save it - all good, except saving job class that inbuilt in CompJob class, that inbuilt in Room class as a Obs. Collection.

What to do to after edit field of job in my datagrid, after saved, i would see changes in xml?

Comment: Have you assigned a job instance with values to compjob?

Comment: 1) What serializer are you using?  2) Where do you assign `CompJobjob`?  3) Can you make a [standalone minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  of the problem?

Comment: 1)XMLSerializer, inbuilt in VS 13. 2)What do you mean? CompJobjob in job class?. 3)I decided to show a lot of code to make it easier to understand.